# "Arrive in the classroom" or "arrive at the classroom"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Tell me which preposition it is the most natural to use with *arrive* in the following context: *in* or *at*.

> The teacher always arrives early **in** the classroom.
>
> The teacher always arrives early **at** the classroom.

Not a long time ago I would have thought that the first sentence is incorrect because *in* is usually used with *arrive* when we talk about bigger places like cities, countries etc. But I have recently come across it with *in* in the context of getting to the classroom in an English textbook. Was it a typo or it is totally natural. For that matter, do I use *in* or *at* in the following sentence?

> I usually arrive **in**/**at** work at eight.

Comment: I go in the classroom. I arrive at the classroom. I am in work (I have a job). I arrive at work at eight, but more usually "I start work at eight."

Comment: @WeatherVane Then there are people who arrive at work at 8 but don't start work until 10, or who start work at 8 but don't leave home! We have to consider semantics as well as syntax...

Comment: @TypeIA I wondered about making that distinction, but still, you arrive "at work" and not "in work".